# Clicking specific favorite tag gives list of much less specific questions

Tags: support, bug

'Form-validation' is one of my favorite tags. But when I click it, I get the questions of all validation categories, of which there are six in total, according to the drop-down menu of the favorite-tag editing form. Three of which I know nothing about, and the fourth I know too little about for the questions to be of interest to me. The questions generally have the tag 'validation', which is the sixth category. But that is not in my group of favorite tags, just 'form-validation'.

Is that by design, a bug, or should I do something differently or additionally?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/validation/synonyms - [form-validation] is a synonym of [validation].

Comment: @Mat: OK, so that would be by design. My next question would then be: has there ever been a discussion about the option of getting only the non-tag-remapped questions, just the ones with the tag that the user selected/clicked? Or: would it be worth my file to file such a feature request? Technically this shouldn't be difficult, should it?

Comment: I would be tempted to ask why html form validation would be synonym for any kind of validation, anywhere. Having such synonym doesn't make sense to me in this case.